# How to populate a List from results of sqlite query in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, win-universal-app

I have a List:

```
public class DateAmountList
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }

List<DateAmountList> itemsList1 = new List<DateAmountList>();
```

I have an sqlite query:

```
var getmonthsquery = "SELECT Date, SUM(Amount) FROM incomeamounts GROUP BY Date";
```

The result looks like you'd expect for the query, something like:

```
Jan, 200
Feb, 250
Mar, 700
```

etc...

I'm not sure why in Windows Universal Apps, but sqliteDataReader is not available even though I've installed the nuget package, so I'd like an alternative way to populate the list with the query results and also the best way to 'execute' the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I'd like an alternative way to populate the list with the query results and also the best way to 'execute' the query.

I am using [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) to [implement SQLite Local Storage in Universal Windows App](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Implement-SQLite-Local-8b13a307):

```
// get the total amount for each date
public static List<DateAmountList> GetTotalAmount()
{
    List<DateAmountList> results = new List<DateAmountList>();
    using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))
    {
        results = conn.Query<DateAmountList>("SELECT Date, SUM(Amount) AS 'Amount' FROM DateAmountList GROUP BY Date");
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here is the [entire sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E754412D31A2DF3D!108&authkey=!AItdZPIchnIJiMI&ithint=file%2Czip) for your reference, and following is the output:

[image]

Comment: got it working as suggested using the SQLite.Net-PLC package, easier when you know which package to use!
If I wanted to bind this to a chartseries, would I do it the same way you have bound to the listview via xaml, or would you recommend in the code behind? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think if you prefer to work with queries directly, you should take a look at [SQLitePCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/) library. Executing query and populating a list is pretty simple:

```
var results = new List<DateAmountList>();

using (var statement = this.connection.Prepare(
    "SELECT Date, SUM(Amount) FROM incomeamounts GROUP BY Date"))
{
    while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
    {
        var dateAmount = new DateAmountList
        {
            Date = DateFromInternalValue(statement[0]),     // This depends on what format you use to store your date
            Amount = (long)statement[1],                    // Could also be: Amount = statement.GetInteger(1),
        };

        results.Add(dateAmount);
    }
}
```

[Here are more samples](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/the-new-portable-class-library-for-sqlite/) of working with SQLitePCL.

As opposite approach, you can try [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) and get nice LINQ-like syntax for working with your sqlite database.

Comment: it's a bit of a minefield trying to find the right nuget package so thanks for your suggestions and example